# Programmatically displaying a view into a colorbox

Tags: views, javascript

Love the module. My use case is to take programatically take the result of a view and load it into a colorbox. I can use views_get_view or views_embed_view to get a result array or a large html string. But how can I pass that to the colorbox?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

https://drupal.org/node/1991948

Comment: Welcome to stack exchange.

Comment: Any tips on how to Set the Image Format To Colorbox? @Sam152

Answer (score 1):

Put your view into a div with a *wrapper* that is hidden (ie, display:none;). Then you can use the following javascript:

```
$.colorbox({
    'inline' : true,
    'href' : $('.views-view-my-view'),
});
```

You must replace the 'href' attribute with the appropriate jQuery collection representing your view. Other customisations to the way your colorbox appears can be [found here](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/).

If you need some advice on placing a view on your page, here is a clean implementation:

```
function MODULE_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  $vars['page']['bottom']['my_view'] = array(
    '#type' => 'container',
    '#attributes' => array(
      'id' => 'my-view-container',
    ),
    'children' => array(
      '#markup' => views_embed_view(...),
    ),
  );
}
```

In this case your selector for colorbox would be `#my-view-container .view`